# Moq - how to verify method call which parameter has been cleaned (a list)

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I've got the following code and I need help to write a unit test for it. I'm using Moq library.

Here's the deal. I have a business class with a dependency to a repository (interface), so I can use it to save my entities to the database. My entity is basically a list of strings. The method AddAndSave, from MyBusinessClass, grab the value it receives as a parameters, put it into the list and call Save method from IRepository. Then, I clear the list of my entity. The code below show this example (I've made it simple so I can explain it here).

There's a unit test, too.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;

namespace TestesGerais
{
    public class MyEntity
    {
        public MyEntity()
        {
            MyList = new List<string>();
        }
        public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IRepository
    {
        void Save(MyEntity entity);
    }

    public class MyBusinessClass
    {
        public IRepository Repository { get; set; }
        private MyEntity _entity = new MyEntity();
        public void AddAndSave(string info)
        {
            _entity.MyList.Add(info);
            Repository.Save(_entity);
            _entity.MyList.Clear();  // for some reason I need to clear it
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest10
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var mock = new Mock<IRepository>();
            MyBusinessClass b = new MyBusinessClass() { Repository = mock.Object };
            b.AddAndSave("xpto");
            mock.Verify(m => m.Save(It.Is<MyEntity>(x => x.MyList[0] == "xpto")), Times.Exactly(1));
        }
    }
}
```

My unit-test check if the IRepository's Save method was called with its parameter (an entity) having one element in the list, and having the value "xpto" in this element.

When I run this test, it turns red with the error message "Test method TestesGerais.UnitTest10.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index".

Ok, this is caused by the list that has been cleaned. If I comment the line "_entity.MyList.Clear();", everything goes well.

My question is: how can I test this without commenting the "Clear" line in my business class, and making sure that my repository's method is called passing the specific value (entity with one element with value "xpto")?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed my unit test using the Callback feature of Moq. This way, I can setup the mock so when AddAndSave is called, the parameter it receives is saved into a variable from my unit test, and I can assert it later.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IRepository>();
        string result = string.Empty;
        mock.Setup(m => m.Save(It.IsAny<MyEntity>())).Callback((MyEntity e) => { result = e.MyList[0]; });
        MyBusinessClass b = new MyBusinessClass() { Repository = mock.Object };
        b.AddAndSave("xpto");
        Assert.AreEqual(result, "xpto");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split your method up a bit. "AddAndSave" isn't all it does. You could then just test the behaviour of the adding and saving bit in isolation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Antony, but the method AddAndSave is an contract that I didn't want to break now, and I need to test its functionality. However, I got a trick to make Moq work in this case, I'll put it here.